# how to write code in c to read integers from a file

Tags: c

I am new to c programming and trying to write code to read from a file a handful of integers into a one dimensional array.  Where the integers are the number of millions of gallons of water provided to a major city over the period of one month and the number of months is the counter variable in the loop. Everytime time i try to run the program and with other attempts it will not run, saying "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)".
here is the data:
123 134 122 128 111 110 98 99 78 98
100 120 122 110 111 123 134 122 128 111 110 98 99 78 98 100 120 122 110 111

thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 50

int main()
{
    int monthly_water_arr[size];
    int num_months;
    FILE *water;

    water=fopen("water.data.txt","r");


    for(num_months=0;num_months<size;num_months++)
    {
        fscanf(water,"%d",&monthly_water_arr[num_months]);
    }
    printf("the number of months is %d\n",num_months);

    fclose(water);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: you should always check the return value from `fopen()`, don't assume it was successful.

Comment: "Everytime time i try to run the program and with other attempts it will not run" --> When a program has trouble and uses `fscanf()` and family, a very good first debugging step is to code a check of the return value of `fscanf().` and `fopen()`. Perhaps: `if 
 (fscanf( water, "%d", &monthly_water_arr[num_months]) != 1) {puts("Error"); exit(-1);}`

Comment: inside of your for loop avoid putting the data directly into the array until you confirm its reading and printing the data correctly ... classic case of divide and conquer a problem ... sure once confirmed the read is OK then directly store into the array however that is not the initial approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the loop to print the data as well. Same way you are doing for reading it.

Comment: That's not what's being asked.